# Can Admin of Azure DevOPS know if a code is downloaded by a user on his local machine

Tags: azure

Is there away we get intimation as admin if someone is downloading or uploading source code in AzureDevOps

Comment: Audit logs same as Shiraz said, but also  you can do some Security Restrictions for Remote Working but it should be 


1. Account in Azure that has minimum Premium Level 1 Azure Active Directory enabled.

2. Azure DevOps Account that is connected to the Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audit logs for this see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

You may not be able to see the difference between if someone just looked at the code or downloaded it to their computer.